# trace of array not changing after item's value was change

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

so i got 2d array as simple map editor.
every tile/cell of the map will have a value of 0 as default and a mouseClick event listener.

```
        for (var i:int =0; i < _numRow; i++)
        {
            _map[i] = new Array  ;
            for (var j:int = 0; j< _numCol; j++)
            {
                //I removed some content
                _tile.val = 0;
                _tile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onMouseClick);

                addChild(_tile);
                _map[i][j] = _tile.val;

            }
        }
```

EDIT: 
Now I click a tile/cell, this will happen. Problem was Commented.

```
private function onMouseClick(e:MouseEvent)
    {

        if (e.currentTarget.val == 0)
        {
            e.currentTarget.val = 1;
            trace(e.currentTarget.val); // trace the output I want, which is 1 of each tile I clicked.     

            e.currentTarget.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(1,0,0);
            trace(_map[0]); // now I check here if _map will be change since _map[x][x] = _tile.val, it should output the change I made above. Like [[1,1,1,0,1,0...]]
        }
```

BUT no the output wasn't change. _map is still = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0...]]
As I said maybe I'm missing simple thing here but I don't know what.
If this still wasn't clear please tell, I will explain it more. Thanks guys.

Comment: is using an array necessary? could you not just increase/decrease the value of each int depending on who you click? also, are the tile's positions fixed and absolute? if so, why not give them each a discreet ID then just return that int every time it's clicked

Comment: i think array is needed because I'm gonna use the traced output of that array (_map) on something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--scratching original answer--

What you want to achieve can be done in 2 ways:

- Store _tile in _map[i][j]
- Or, store {"num": 0} in _tile.val and assign _map[i][j] to _tile.val. Then, while fetching value from _map, use _map[i][j].num and update value in _tile as _tile.val.num = 1.

The problem that you are currently facing can be pictorially shown as:

```
_map[i][j]---|
             |  |----|
             |->|  0 |
_tile.val----|  |----|
```

But, after you assign 1 to _tile.val, the result would look something like:

```
_map[i][j]-->|-----|
             |  0  |
             |-----|

_tile.val--->|-----|
             |  1  |
             |-----|
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for late reply guys. BTW It's assigned as number. Check my edit, If that would be more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try tracing the whole _map array (not just _map[0]). Also, I'm assuming that there are _numRow*_numCol tiles on screen. And you are updating one tile at a time as it's clicked. I'm just trying to verify that the trace shows _map[i][j] value for the tile which is clicked.

Comment: Even the whole _map wasn't change.

Comment: could you explain why "my" recent way won't work? Since _map[i][j] = _tile.val shouldn't be trace(_map) will output _tile.val too, even when i change it in runtime?

Comment: hey nevermind what I said. I just modified my code and added some from your idea. Thank you so much.